# Dash suppress error "A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback"

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a complex Dash app where different layouts are displayed depending on some inputs. These output layouts (created in callbacks) contain some inputs.

Because those inputs are not defined yet in the layout, I have the error "A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback."

Is there a way nowadays to get rid of this error other than playing with the CSS style "visibility" to make them exist in the HTML code, but invisible to the user?

I tried to add `suppress_callback_exceptions=True` when creating the app but it is not working.

I am using Dash v2.9.3.

```py
from dash import dcc, Dash, html, Input, Output, callback


app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Store(id="store_filters", storage_type="memory"),
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id="choice_filters",
            options=["filters1", "filters2", "filters3"],
            value="filters1",
            inline=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id="filters"),
    ]
)


@callback(Output("filters", "children"), Input("choice_filters", "value"))
def update_filters(choice_filters):
    if choice_filters == "filters1":
        layout = [dcc.Input(id="input1", type="text")]
    elif choice_filters == "filters2":
        layout = [dcc.Input(id="input2", type="text")]
    elif choice_filters == "filters3":
        layout = [dcc.Input(id="input3", type="text")]
    else:
        layout = []
    return layout


@callback(
    Output("store_filters", "data"),
    [
        Input("input1", "value"),
        Input("input2", "value"),
        Input("input3", "value"),
    ],
)
def filters_result(input1, input2, input3):
    filters = {"filter1": input1, "filter2": input2, "filter3": input3}
    print("Last filters entered : ")
    print(filters)
    return filters


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8222)
```

Comment: Afaik, `suppress_callback_exceptions` won't allow you to make a callback process non-existent input at the execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of @Dmitry's answer (+1), I modified and extended a few aspects of the code:

- The functionality of the pattern-matching is printed live to the app for the sake of easier demonstration
- Using `dcc.Store` to persist the dynamically generated `dcc.Input` components' user-entered text values
- Contextualizing the code into a fully working demo app

E.g., the following:

```py
from dash import dcc, Dash, html, Input, Output, callback, ALL, State

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Store(id="store_filters", storage_type="session", data={}),
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id="choice_filters",
            options=[
                {"label": "Filter 1", "value": "Filter 1"},
                {"label": "Filter 2", "value": "Filter 2"},
                {"label": "Filter 3", "value": "Filter 3"},
            ],
            value="Filter 1",
            inline=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id="filters"),
        html.Div(id="filters_output"),
    ],
    style={"margin": "10%", "textAlign": "center"},
)


@callback(
    Output("filters", "children"),
    Input("choice_filters", "value"),
    State("store_filters", "data"),
)
def update_filters(choice_filters, stored_data):
    stored_value = stored_data.get(choice_filters, "")

    filter_input = dcc.Input(
        id={"type": "filter", "name": choice_filters},
        type="text",
        placeholder=f"Enter value for {choice_filters}",
        value=stored_value,
    )

    return [filter_input]


@callback(
    Output("filters_output", "children"),
    Output("store_filters", "data"),
    Input({"type": "filter", "name": ALL}, "value"),
    State({"type": "filter", "name": ALL}, "id"),
    State("store_filters", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def filters_result(filter_values, filter_ids, stored_data):
    filters = {
        id_value["name"]: value
        for id_value, value in zip(filter_ids, filter_values)
    }

    for key, value in filters.items():
        stored_data[key] = value

    filters_output = [
        html.Div([html.H2(f"{key}:"), html.P(f"{value}")])
        for key, value in filters.items()
    ]

    return filters_output, stored_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8222)
```

results in:

[image: Video screenshot recording of demo dash app with pattern-matching dynamic callbacks and components]

Comment: I'm struggling a little to adapt to my complex app, but I believe it is what i was looking for !

Comment: @gdevaux Happy to try and help if you want to provide any specifics on what you're struggling with. (Perhaps a new question might be the best format or if it's not too complex here in comments.)

Comment: I had some trouble with filling `stored_data` when there were some None values, but I fixed it with `stored_data = {**stored_data, **filters}` instead of the for loop. It's all good now, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe this kind of dynamic filtering is handled by [pattern-matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks). Here is the idea:

### Adding components

```py
@callback(
    Output('filters', 'children'),
    Input('choice_filters', 'value'))
def update_filters(choice_filters):

    filter_input = dcc.Input(
        id={'type': 'filter', 'name': choice_filters},
        type='text')

    return [filter_input]
```

### Handling in callbacks

```py
# from dash import ALL

@callback(
    Output('store_filters', 'data'),
    Input({'type': 'filter', 'name': ALL}, 'value'),
    State({'type': 'filter', 'name': ALL}, 'id'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def filters_result(filter_values, filter_ids):

    filters = {id_value[0]['name']: id_value[1] for id_value in
               zip(filter_ids, filter_values)}

    print(f"Last filters entered : {filters}")

    return filters
```